# I want to break my oath, should I give kaffarah before or after breaking it?

Tags: oaths, kaffarah

I swore about not doing an act, it's not a sin, but now after sometime, I want to do it. Should I do it and then give the kaffarah or should I give the kaffarah and then do it? Couldn't find answers on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pay Kaffarah after breaking the oath. As stated in the hadith:

> وإذا حلفت على يمين فرأيت غيرها خيرا منها، فأت الذي هو خير، وكفر عن يمينك
>
> If you take an oath to do something and later on find another thing, better than that, then do what is better and make expiation for your oath
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/84)</sup>

And there exists Ijma' on its validity:

> وأجمعوا على أن الحنث قبل الكفارة مباح
>
> They have a consensus that breaking an oath before payment of Kaffarah is permissible
>
> <sup>— [al-Tamhid - Ibn 'Abd al-Barr](https://shamela.ws/book/236/7477) and also see [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura5-aya89.html#qortobi)</sup>

As for paying Kaffarah before breaking the oath: The majority states that it is permissible but some of them hold that it is preferable to pay the Kaffarah after breaking the oath. Other madhabs do not consider it permissible to pay the Kaffarah before breaking the oath. The evidence used by those who consider it permissible includes the ahadith such as:

> إذا حلف أحدكم على اليمين فرأى خيرا منها فليكفرها وليأت الذي هو خير
>
> If one of you swears an oath, then he sees something that is better than it, let him offer expiation for it then do that which is better than it
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1651c)</sup>

---

**Ref:** https://islamqa.info/en/answers/324534/